# Is somebody able to troubleshoot this glitch in my Adobe Animate game?

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, animate.css

[Video of my glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nwsLZkqmxrQ)

As you can see from the video when the ball hits the left side of the screen in that certain position the ball glitches out, however, this doesn't happen on the right side of the screen. Here is my code.

```
var xDirection:Number = 10;
var yDirection:Number = -10;

var targetX:Number = player_mc.x;
var easing:Number = 7;

var playerScore:Number;

function resetBallPosition():void
{
    xDirection = 10;
    yDirection = -10;
    ball_mc.x = 2
    ball_mc.y = 11
}

function checkHitLocation(player:MovieClip):void
{
    var hitPercent:Number;
    var ballPosition:Number = ball_mc.x - player_mc.x;
    hitPercent = (ballPosition / player_mc.width);
    xDirection = hitPercent * 30;
    yDirection *= 1.025;
}

function initializeGame(event:MouseEvent):void
{

    playerScore = 0;
    showScore();
    showStart();
    player_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
    ball_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
    bg_mc.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, initializeGame);

}



function endGame():void

{

    player_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, movePlayer);
    ball_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
    bg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, initializeGame);
    text_mc.text = 'CLICK TO PLAY AGAIN';
    text_mc.visible = true
    start_mc.visible = false;

}

function moveBall(event:Event):void
{
    if(ball_mc.x <= 0)
    {
        xDirection *= -1;
        text_mc.visible = false;
        start_mc.visible = false;
    }
    else if(ball_mc.x >= stage.stageWidth - ball_mc.width)
    {
        xDirection *= -1;
        text_mc.visible = false;
        start_mc.visible = false;
    }
    if(ball_mc.hitTestObject(player_mc))
    {
        yDirection *= -1;
        ball_mc.y = player_mc.y - ball_mc.height - player_mc.height/2;
        checkHitLocation(player_mc);
        playerScore ++;
        showScore();
        text_mc.visible = false;
        start_mc.visible = false;
    }
    if(ball_mc.y <= 0)
    {
        yDirection *= -1;
        //resetBallPosition();
        text_mc.visible = false
        start_mc.visible = false;
    }
    else if(ball_mc.y >= stage.stageHeight - ball_mc.height)
    {
        endGame();
        resetBallPosition();
        showScore();

    }
    ball_mc.x += xDirection;
    ball_mc.y += yDirection;

}

function movePlayer(event:Event):void
{
    if(this.mouseX <= player_mc.width/2)
    {
        targetX = 0;
        start_mc.visible = false;
    }
    else if(this.mouseX >= stage.stageWidth - player_mc.width/2)
    {
        targetX = stage.stageWidth - player_mc.width;
        start_mc.visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
    targetX = this.mouseX - player_mc.width/2;
    start_mc.visible = false;
    }
    player_mc.x += (targetX - player_mc.x) / easing;
}

function showScore():void
{
    score_mc.text = "Score: " + playerScore;
    start_mc.visible = false;
}

function showStart():void
{
    start_mc.text = 'CLICK SCREEN TO START';
    start_mc.visible = true;

}

showStart();


bg_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, initializeGame);
```

Thanks in advance, only a beginner so I'm not to sure where the problem is in my code so even some indication of where to look would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Because **xDirection *= -1;** is asking for a glitch. If the ball cannot escape the position in one go, it will forever stitch its way with **x < 0**.

You don't want to negate the axis ball speed, you want to ensure it goes positive on the left side and negative on the right side.

```
var aLeft:Number = 0;
var aRight:Number = stage.stageWidth - ball_mc.width;

if (ball_mc.x < aLeft)
{
    // Make it POSITIVE.
    xDirection = Math.abs(xDirection);

    // Fix the position as if the ball ricocheted.
    ball_mc.x = aLeft + (aLeft - ball_mc.x);
}
else if (ball_mc.x > aRight)
{
    // Make it NEGATIVE.
    xDirection = -Math.abs(xDirection);

    // Fix the position as if the ball ricocheted.
    ball_mc.x = aRight + (aRight - ball_mc.x);
}
```

The same goes for Y-axis coordinates and speed.